# How to get Click Event of Windows Drives in C#?

Tags: c#

How to get Click Event of Windows Drives in C# ?
E.g -> Lets say we have D: drive when we click right click on it we get several option slike Open,Explore etc... when we click on anyone say Open intenally some click event get fired .
I want to know how i get that click event in c# ?
Any code snippet...

Comment: This is pretty much the same question you asked already - why not go back to that question and update it? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3386288/how-to-get-local-mapped-drive-click-event-in-c

Comment: You can't do this directly in C#. What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: the previous question has been closed now.

Comment: The tricky thing is that your shell extension code will run inside the "explorer.exe" process, not your own program.  You will get better answers here if you tell people what your end goal is in trying to capture the events (i.e. what do you want your program to do in the end?)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have to register as a Shell Extension, [Here is a guide](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/shell/shellextguide1.aspx) that walkthrough the process.

Comment: +1 You pretty much have to do this in C++, though. C# shell extensions aren't supported.

Comment: @Tim: However you can write in C++/CLI or in C++ and call from C#